# How to access a Form field value in Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-form

I'm trying to take text in a text box and on OK do a replacement.

I can't access the form fields on click of the button.

This gives an error for invalid use of property.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim body As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set Version = ActiveDocument.Controls("TextBox1").Text
    body = OutMail.HTMLBody
    
    body = Replace(body, "XYZ", Version)
    OutMail.HTMLBody
End Sub
```

[image: Form]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code is in the code-behind of the UserForm, then you access the controls on the UserForm directly eg to get the text in TextBox1 you just do `TextBox1.Text`.

Also don't use `Set` when assigning a value to a String (only to objects).

You could re-write your code as follows

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OutMail As MailItem
    Dim body As String, Version As String
    Set OutMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Version = TextBox1.Text
    body = OutMail.HTMLBody
    body = Replace(body, "XYZ", Version)
    OutMail.HTMLBody = body
End Sub
```

Note this will error if no email is currently open/being edited. And the 'replace' is case-sensitive (ie only "XYZ" is replaced, not "xyz" etc).